# Is there a way to blur the background but not the text

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to blur the `background`, but allow for the text and buttons to be kept not blurred
Also this is a small cover on the background, Not the background so a simple `<p>` after the code wont work

```css
.middlecoversecond{
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  height: 550px;
  position: center;
  background-color: #dddddd;  
  border-style: solid; 
  border-width: 3px; 
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="middlecoversecond">
  <h1>More Stuff2</h1>
  <p> Other of this</p>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a very cool `backdrop-filter` which is still in draft (part of CSS Filter Effects Module 2 Editor's Draft), hence very limited support at this stage. See [CSS Tricks: backdrop-filter](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/). So at the moment, to have something work on most modern browsers, you'll need to create a separate element with the blurred background.

Answer (score 0):

Put yours styles to another div and set width and height 100% to the div parent
I hope it helps you

```
<div>
<div class="backgroundblurinpositionabsolute"></div>
<h1>More Stuff2</h1>
<p> Other of this</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. But I am not sure what your expected outcome is. I think creating another `<div>` outside of `<div class="middlecoversecond">` and blurring it while keeping `<div class="middlecoversecond">` unblurred is another workaround.

```css
.middlecoversecond{
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  height: 550px;
  position: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.blurred
{
  z-index: 0;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-width: 3px; 
  background-color: #dddddd;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(10px);
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="blurred"></div>
<div class="middlecoversecond">
  <h1>More Stuff2</h1>
  <p> Other of this</p>
</div>
```